# Dialyzer cannot recognize error in function using polymorphic types

Tags: types, elixir, dialyzer

### Background

I am trying out polymorphic typing with dialyzer. As an example I am using the famous `Option` type (aka, Maybe Monad) that is now prevalent in many other languages these days.

```
defmodule Test do
  @type option(t) :: some(t) | nothing
  @type some(t) :: [{:some, t}]
  @type nothing :: []

  @spec validate_name(String.t()) :: option(String.t())
  def validate_name(name) do
    if String.length(name) > 0 do
      [{:some, name}]
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, the function `validate_name` should return (by spec definition) `[{:some, String.t}] | []`.

The issue here is that in reality, the function is returning `[{:some, String.t}] | nil`. `nil` is not the same as empty list `[]`.

### Problem

Given this issue, I would expect dialyzer to complain. However it gladly accepts this erroneous spec:

```
$ mix dialyzer
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Finding suitable PLTs
Checking PLT...
[:compiler, :currying, :elixir, :gradient, :gradualizer, :kernel, :logger, :stdlib, :syntax_tools]
PLT is up to date!
No :ignore_warnings opt specified in mix.exs and default does not exist.

Starting Dialyzer
[
  check_plt: false,
  init_plt: '/home/user/Workplace/fl4m3/grokking_fp/_build/dev/dialyxir_erlang-24.2.1_elixir-1.13.2_deps-dev.plt',
  files: ['/home/user/Workplace/fl4m3/grokking_fp/_build/dev/lib/grokking_fp/ebin/Elixir.Book.beam',
   '/home/user/Workplace/fl4m3/grokking_fp/_build/dev/lib/grokking_fp/ebin/Elixir.DealingWithListsOfLists.beam',
   '/home/user/Workplace/fl4m3/grokking_fp/_build/dev/lib/grokking_fp/ebin/Elixir.Event.beam',
   '/home/user/Workplace/fl4m3/grokking_fp/_build/dev/lib/grokking_fp/ebin/Elixir.FlatMapsVSForComprehensions.beam',
   '/home/user/Workplace/fl4m3/grokking_fp/_build/dev/lib/grokking_fp/ebin/Elixir.ImmutableValues.beam',
   ...],
  warnings: [:unknown]
]
Total errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Unnecessary Skips: 0
done in 0m1.09s
done (passed successfully)
```

Furthermore, no matter what I put in the `else` branch, the result is always a "happy dialyzer".

### Question

At this point, the only logical solution I can think of is that dialyzer is *only* concerned with the happy path. Meaning, it will ignore my `else` branch.

If dialzyer is only ever concerned with happy paths, then this would explain the issue (it is called success typing after all) but it also means it will totally miss a bunch of errors in my code.

- Is my assumption about dialyzer correct?
- Is there a way to make it more precise in finding errors, or is this a limitation of the algorithm used by dialyzer ? (and therefore no fix is possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> also means it will totally miss a bunch of errors in my code.

Your understanding is correct, dialyzer is not a statical type system and it will only be able to detect a subset of errors that will result in a confirmed type clash. This [detailed article](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/dialyzer) explains the design and trade-offs behind dialyzer.

There are some warning flags though, like `underspecs` / `overspecs` / `specdiffs`, than can be enabled to detect more categories of errors: the list can be found [here](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html) and dialyxir supports them as [command line options](https://hexdocs.pm/dialyxir/readme.html#command-line-options).

If running `mix dialyzer --overspecs` (or `--specdiffs`), you should get:

```
your_file.ex:6:missing_range
The type specification is missing types returned by function.

Function:
Test.validate_name/1

Type specification return types:
[{:some, binary()}]

Missing from spec:
nil
```

Running `mix dialyzer.explain missing_range`:

```
Function spec declares a list of types, but function returns value
outside stated range.

This error only appears with the :overspecs flag.
```

Edit: Since OTP 25, Dialyzer will introduce [two new flags](https://www.erlang.org/news/153#dialyzer): `missing_return` and `extra_return`, similar respectively to `overspecs` and `underspecs`, but with less false positives and more usable in practice.

`missing_return` will catch the `missing_range` example above, but without returning a lot of noisy `contract_subtype` warnings that you might not really care about, like `overspecs` does.

Comment: Ok, so why do I have to use the overspecs flag? Dialyzer does not have an understanding of a happy path in code (who tells dialyzer that one branch of my if statement is bad and another is good?). Does the tool ignore `else` branches by default?

Comment: I edited my answer to include an article that explains dialyzer and how it differs from a static type system. Quoting it: "Dialyzer's type system thus made the decision not to prove that a program is error-free when it comes to types, but only to find as many errors as possible without ever contradicting what happens in the real world". In your case, `else` might just be dead-code that never gets called in practice, so dialyzer just ignores it because it cannot be sure a conflict will actually happen. "keeping in mind that Dialyzer is optimistic ... is vital to working efficiently with it."

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix interestingly, dialyzer just got new flags in the latest OTP rc, so I updated my post to mention them. While I had a lot of false positives using `overspecs` and couldn't really use it on my projects, `missing_return` seems to do exactly what I needed and seems to only catch the kind of error you actually would expect, so this is an exciting improvement.

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

**Disclaimer:** This is a summary of my adventure to find an answer to this question. For the short version, check @[sabiwara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13979518/sabiwara)'s [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71150710/1337392).

After talking with many folks I have come to understand that as long as 1 path in my code leads to a successful execution that is compatible with the specs I provide, dialyzer will not complain.

There may be many paths that break, but as long as 1 works, dialzyer is happy.

In my specific case, because I have a branch that returns `[{:some, String.t}]` dialyzer does not complain, because I have 1 branch that succeeds.

This can be better summarized in the quote from [Type Specifications and Eralng](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/dialyzer):

> The other option is then to have a type system that will not *prove* the absence of errors, but will do a best effort at detecting whatever it can. You can make such detection really good, but it will never be perfect. It's a tradeoff to be made.

In fact, the article mentioned above, has an example case very similar to my own:

```erlang
main() ->
    X = case fetch() of
        1 -> some_atom;
        2 -> 3.14
    end,
    convert(X).

convert(X) when is_atom(X) -> {atom, X}.
```

Which also does not trigger dialyzer. According to the article:

> From our point of view, it appears that at some point in time, the call to `convert/1` will fail.
> (...)
> Dialyzer doesn't think so. (...) because there is the *possibility* that the function call to `convert/1` succeeds at some point, Dialyzer will keep silent. No type error is reported in this case.

This is quite enlightening and I am convinced this is what is happening in my case.

### Will dialyzer ever understand what is going on?

To be fair, this error can be caught by dialyzer if we use some flags, namelly `--overspecs` (for this case) and its sister `--underspecs` (which we don't need for this case).

After some research I was able to find a mailing list that details the behaviour of these flags in a mathematical format:

- [[erlang-questions] Dialyzer underspecs and overspecs options](https://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2017-March/091997.html)

From it:

> Let SpecIn be a set of @spec inputs and RealIn be a set of inputs as inferred by Dialyzer from real code, then:
>
> - The Input Contract is satisfied when SpecIn <= RealIn (where <= is a non-strict subset operation). See over_in in demo code below.
> - The Input Contract violation is detected by -Wunderspecs option when SpecIn > RealIn. See under_in below.
>
> It is easy to see in the code:
>
> - It’s OK for over_in to declare that it only accepts :a and :b while it also happens to accept :c. Maybe suboptimal, but fine.
> - It’s NOT OK for under_in to claim that it accepts :a, :b and :c and break if :c is passed. Rejecting :c would break the caller.
>
> Let SpecOut be a set of @spec outputs and RealOut be a set of outputs as inferred by Dialyzer from real code, then:
>
> - The Output Contract is satisfied when SpecOut >= RealOut (where >= is a non-strict superset operation). See under_out below.
> - The Output Contract violation is detected by -Woverspecs option when SpecOut < RealOut. See over_out below.
>
> It is easy to see in the code:
>
> - It’s OK for under_out to declare that it returns :a, :b and :c, while currently it only returns :a and :b. Maybe future implementations will return :c as well.
> - It’s NOT OK for over_out to declare that it returns :a and :b, but to also return :c sometimes. Returning :c would break the caller.

And indeed if I run `mix dialyzer --overspecs` with this sample, dialzyer does complain becasue:

> The Output Contract violation is detected by -Woverspecs option when SpecOut < RealOut. See over_out below.

Where RealOut is `[] | [t] | nil`  and SpecOut is `[] | [t]`.
Therefore, a contract violation is detected.

Error shown:

```
lib/test.ex:6:missing_range
The type specification is missing types returned by function.

Function:
Test.validate_name/1

Type specification return types:
[{:some, binary()}]

Missing from spec:
nil
```

This was a wild ride through Dialyzer, and a revision I quite honestly needed. During the whole ordeal I learned about a couple of dialyzer flags and I refreshed my memory on success typing (which I absolutely needed to).

Thank you everyone for participating !