# Dialyzer check only the first case of the function

Tags: erlang, dialyzer

Why does Dialyzer check only the first case of the function?

```erlang
-spec f(integer()) -> integer().
f(0) -> 0;
f(_) -> test.
```

Proceeding with analysis... done in 0m0.25s
done (passed successfully)

The version with "case" also passes the check:

```erlang
-spec f(integer()) -> integer().
f(N) -> 
    case N of
      0 -> 1;
      _ -> test
    end.
```

Dialyzer version is 4.4.3

Comment: Although the example is in Elixir and not Erlang, this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145676/dialyzer-cannot-recognize-error-in-function-using-polymorphic-types) is quite similar. Using the `missing_return` flag should catch this.

Answer (score 0):

If passes, because you have just told it what the function is supposed to do. If you try and *call* the function with different arguments from the specification, then you would get a warning:

> test() -> f(not_an_integer).

gives the dialyzer output:

```
   f.erl:8:13: The call f:f    
         ('not_an_integer') breaks the contract.   
          (integer()) -> integer()
```

Comment: This is ridiculous, but yeah, the typing takes usage into account

Comment: Although, your answer doesn't explain why `f(123)` doesn't throw a warning

Comment: ...because 123 is an integer?

Comment: But `test` is not, which breaks the return type promise if you run `f(123)`